# How do i stream files from a website to my app?

Tags: android

I feel like 'stream' isn't the right word for it but how do i, let's say on my website i have jpg/mp3 files and i want to get these said files and make them appear in my android app.

Okay so...
 1.) I set up a site then upload files there. 
2.) then somehow retrieve files from said site to my android app.

 3.) Play mp3's hence 'stream'  
 do i put these files(jpg/png/mp3/mp4) on a sql database? then access it from the application? that's only method i could think of but i would like to know if there's another way to do it.

Oh and a the site i mentioned is where i just upload these files, so i plan to put a search bar on my app then if someone searches "soccerball.jpg" for example then it'll grab the file from the site then make it appear on the app.

Comment: They just need to be on the filesystem served by the webserver.  Then you access them by URL on the device and download them.

Comment: @GabeSechan interesting,  if you don't mind can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: he means if you have a server, u can store your files there. then u can use php (for example) as an API endpoint to access them.

Comment: @DroiDev Its a server.  Servers serve files, by default.  You don't need any endpoint to access them, unless you're looking to authenticate users.

Comment: @GabeSechan for some sort of security, its probably best instead of slapping a URL in a app... unless its for his personal use.

Comment: @DroiDev so i use php to retrieve files? what am in for if i'm not to use php?

Comment: @panzerkampf is this going to be a published app or for personal use?

Comment: I feel that you are trying to display data from another site that isn't yours. If that's the case and you don't have access to the site's endpoints, just do some webscrapping. Use Jsoup or some sort of DOM parsing library, get the urls of the mp3 sources or images and display'em. All streaming libraries including Android's MediaPlayer can work just with the URL, you don't need to download the whole file.

Comment: @DroiDev published.

Comment: @4gus71n Hi!, i'm planning to set up a site first maybe get a plan of 2GB to start it up, it's a site where only i can access and it's where i dump pictures and videos.
and on the app theres a search bar then i can see results from the files i uploaded. i've seen apps on the play store that is only 5-10mb max, then when you open it you can watch videos probably streamed from somewhere. i just want to know the procedures and i am very lost. do i need to set up a website first? or can i link it via url from the fileserver of the webhost i am about to use? thank you!

Comment: if its a published app you need to use an API to get the links. you do not want them stored within your local app. you can use PHP, firebase, parse-server